# Windows Patch List Location

Tags: windows-registry, updates, windows-server

Can anyone tell me the location of the file, reg key, that contains the patches/updates to Windows?  This is for both Server 2003 and 2008.  They appear to be different locations but, I cannot seem to find the location of the list on either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want a list of updates then do this,  at a command prompt type

wmic qfe

wmic /node:servern qfe  if you want to do remote qfe queries.

Comment: That works but, do you know where it loads the data from?

Comment: unfortunately (and I have not verified this) the location changes based on the installer version!